# select subset of columns when using col_type() in readr

Tags: r, readr

I'm trying to read in a file with read_delim() and select a subset (a long run) of columns to define as a specific type.

As an example, I have a file with 6 columns. I want to select column 1 ('name') as character, but then select columns 2-6 as integer. I can do this by manually specifying the column names:

```
df <- read_delim(file = "data.txt", col_type = list(name = col_character(), id_1 = col_integer(), id_2 = col_integer(), id_3 = col_integer(), id_4 = col_integer(), id_5 = col_integer()), delim = " ")
```

But my data has 100s of columns and I want to select a subset/run of columns without writing them out manually.

I've tried:

```
df <- read_delim(file = "data.txt", col_type = list(name = col_character(), id_1:id_5 = col_integer()), delim = " ")
```

and

```
df <- read_delim(file = "data.txt", col_type = list(name = col_character(), select('id_1':'id_5') = col_integer()), delim = " ")
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"col_type = list(name = col_character(), select('id_1':'id_5') ="
```

I'm sure this is very simple but I've spent hours and hours trying to work it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to pass a named `list` with `setNames`

```
df <- read_delim(file = "data.txt", 
     col_type = setNames( c(list(col_character()),  
           rep(list(col_integer()), 5)),
             c("name", paste0("id_", 1:5))), delim = " ")
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you!

Comment: Can this be adapted to use regular expressions in the named parsers? For example, if the column names all start with 'id_' but are followed by a complex code. I have tried: `col_type = setNames( c(list(col_character()), rep(list(col_integer()), 5)), c("name", rep(regex("id_"), 5))), delim = " ")` but get error that named parsers dont match column names.